# Using python subprocess to call Sox in synth mode on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sox

I am writing a small python file to generate specific frequencies using sox on the raspberry pi through the audio jack. I've installed Sox and can call it happily through the command line but I want to call it in my python file using subprocess in the following way:

```
x = subprocess.Popen('play -V -r 44100 -n synth 30 sin 130+150 vol +2dB')
```

However, this always gives me the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have read various other posts on this and can successfully call this with shell = true as follows:

```
x=subprocess.call('play -V -r 44100 -n synth 30 sin 130+150 vol +2dB', shell=True)
```

but I don't want to use the shell. I am hoping to be able to tell if the process is still running and I also want to investigate pausing and restarting the sox process. I have not looked at this yet.

In another post, someone has suggested using the whole path to Sox such as this:

```
x=subprocess.call('/usr/bin/play -V -r 44100 -n synth 30 sin 130+150 vol +2dB')
```

and although this is the path to this command on my system (using which sox) and I can call this directly from the command line, it  returns the same error when used in my python file. Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `Popen('/usr/bin/play ...'.split())` might work because Popen expects a list of parameters not a single string IIRC. Or add `shell=True` to your call (read up on why this is bad)

Comment: thank you so much. I didn't mention that I had tried splitting arguments to no avail in a list, but using split() seems to do the trick. Doing it this way rather than using shell seems to give me more options for polling it and pausing / unpausing etc. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! This is most likely because when creating a list manually, logically people tend to pair parameters with its value as one list item, while in fact it's expected of the list that both parameter and value are in a separate list entity. Also, in the long run, `shlex.split("cmd string")` is preferred because it will preserve sentences as one object when encapsulated in quotes while regular split won't. You're more than welcome :)

Comment: @Torxed - you should add this as an answer! It took an hour of searching to find this solution buried in a comment. Thanks so much for finding the solution for me